# copy-paste using javascript

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I have text in JS variable and I want that to be copied in clipboard on a button's click.
I need this in Javascript and code must not be browser-specific.

Comment: Most browsers seem to block JavaScript access nowadays for security reasons.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244822/copy-paste-content-to-and-from-clipboard-using-javascript / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459276/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-in-firefox-3-5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453198/copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) works fully within the browser's security restrictions. It uses Flash to copy to the clipboard, accessing a Flash movie from JavaScript. To work around Flash's own security limitation, it must be overlaid on top of some element of your page (*e.g.* a button) that the user will have to click. Read its instructions page for more details.